# How to add view to backstack (android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment-backstack

I am currently building an app using the new material design principals. 
In the app, when the user clicks on a list view item, a panel slides up from bottom of the screen, and houses a fragment. 
My problem is that when the panel is expanded, and the user clicks the back button, the app closes, instead of the panel sliding back down. 
No new activities or fragments are launched when the user clicks the list view row, so I am not sure how to get this working correctly.

What I need is to make it so that when the user clicks the listview row, the panel expands, and when the user then clicks the back button, a method is called to close the panel(currently pressing the back button closes the app).

If someone could explain how I add a view change to the back stack, or how I can get the desired behavior, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks 
Corey :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle back press on your activity to call the method to close the panel.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks heaps! Corey :)